# Unable to run filter on RethinkDB in Golang

Tags: go, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-go, gorethink

I am trying to run a filter on a nested property of RethinkDB data in Golang using `GoRethink` library.

But, I am getting this error:

> gorethink: Cannot convert OBJECT to SEQUENCE in: r.DB("uc_dev").Table("unverified_requests").Filter(func(var_‌​5 r.Term) r.Term { return var_5.Field("user").Map(func(var_6 r.Term) r.Term { return var_6.Field("email") }).Eq("myemail@gmail.com") })

Here is my code:

```
type User struct {
    Id        string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    FirstName string `json:"firstName,omitempty"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastName,omitempty"`
    Email     string `json:"email,omitempty"`
    Password  string `json:"password,omitempty"`
    Salt      string `json:"salt,omitempty"`
}

type UnverifiedUserRequest struct {
    Id    string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Token string `json:"token,omitempty"`
    User  User   `json:"user,omitempty"`
}

db.Table("unverified_requests").Filter(func(row r.Term) r.Term {
    return row.Field("user").Map(func(user r.Term) r.Term {
        return user.Field("email")
    }).Eq(email)
}).Run(session)
```

Comment: I'm no rethinkdb expert, but it seems to me like you're using the map function on a single object, but it is designed to work on each element of sequences, which is an ordered collection. This is just a guess, but I think you want `row.Field("user").Field("email")`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, here is what I needed to do:

```
result, err = db.Table("unverified_requests").Filter(func(uu r.Term) r.Term {
    return uu.Field("user").Field("email").Eq(email)
}).Run(session)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to map over a single object. Maybe this would work:

```
db.Table("unverified_requests").Filter(r.Row.Field("user").Field("email").Eq(email)).Run(session)
```